# How to understand if an update statement worked successfully?

Tags: php, mysql

In my program I want update some information, so I used:

```
 return ($result->rowCount() == 1)? true: false;
```

this way, if you save information without any change, `false` is returned and this is not the result usually we expect.

I change my function to this one

```
try{
        $result=$db->prepare($sql);
            $result->execute($arr);
            return true; 
        }catch(Exception $e){
            return false;   
        }
```

Is it the best way? Does this way guarantee that the update statement worked or not?

Comment: I does ensure that update query was executed on your database, it's quite logical behaviour because why would you execute update query if nothing will be changed?

Comment: Why don't yo use the functions to show errors that are implemented in all database connectors? Can't point you to the documentation here, since you did not tell us _which_ database connector you are using. But I am sure you did read the documentation. Em... you _did_ read the documentation, didn't you?

Comment: @insanebits in some case you may need it

Comment: @arkascha database connector?

Comment: @Peymanabdollahy of course you do, but if you have a sql error you would need to throw exception instead of error since that breaks your application.

Comment: @insanebits yes but what's the best way for this situation?

Comment: You mention some object (`$db`) and ask how to find out if that one runs into an error. But you never mention what kind of object that is. So what database connector is used here. Because on that depends, what error functions are available. It _might_ be `mysqli` or `PDO`, but it might also be some self implemented wrapper class around the old `mysql` adapter - we cannot _guess_ that. You have to tell us.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `$db` is instance of `PDO`

When you run `PDO::prepare` you can detect sql syntax error and when you run `PDO::execute` you will be sure that syntax is correct. Then application is resposible for knowing if update should have updated something or not.

So here is some sample code:

```
function update($db, $sql)
{
    $preparedSql = $db->prepare($sql);

    if(!$preparedSql) {
        // syntax error occured
        $errorInfo = $db->errorInfo();
        // handle error
        return false;
    }

    $db->execute($preparedSql);
    // note that rowCount returns 0 when none updated
    return $db->rowCount();
}
```

In your application

```
$result = update($db, $sql);

if($result === false)
{
     // error occured
} elseif($result === 0) {
     // zero rows updated
} else {
     // some rows were updated
}
```

Note that it's not tested and for learning purposes only, `update` function should accept to bind parameters for real world application

Comment: error occured just in prepare time? if in execute values not sent to database what happend? or with wrong parameters? assume we send parameters as array to execute